# What argument can we pass to super()?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I created a `Vehicle` class and want to also have a `Car` class derived from it that calls the parent constructor to set `name` and `color`. However I'm getting this error:

```
super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

This is my code:

```
class Vehicle:

    def __init__(self, name, color):
        self.__name = name      # __name is private to Vehicle class
        self.__color = color

    def getColor(self):         # getColor() function is accessible to class Car
        return self.__color

    def setColor(self, color):  # setColor is accessible outside the class
        self.__color = color

    def getName(self):          # getName() is accessible outside the class
        return self.__name
        self.__model = model

    def getDescription(self):
        return self.getName() + self.__model + " in " + self.getColor() + " color"


class Car(Vehicle):

    def __init__(self, name, color, model):
        # call parent constructor to set name and color
        super().__init__(name,  color)
        self.__model = model

    def getDescription(self):
        return self.getName() + self.__model + " in " + self.getColor() + " color"

# in method getDescrition we are able to call getName(), getColor() because they are
# accessible to child class through inheritance

c = Car("Ford Mustang", "red", "GT350")
print(c.getDescription())
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think the usage of super changed between python2 and python3.

Comment: What version of python3 are you using?

Comment: I use python version 3

Comment: What release version?

Comment: This works for me using Python 3.5.0

Comment: I get the same error as OP when using Python 2.7.11.

Comment: oh my god sorry, just typed python on the terminal and it said python version2.7.6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Python 3 - nice

In Python 3 this works:

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Vehicle __init__() called')

class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

car = Car()
```

prints:

```
Vehicle __init__() called
```

### Python 2 - more work

Trying the same thing in Python 2 causes problems:

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Vehicle __init__() called')

class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


car = Car()
```

Throws this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

We need to supply the own class as first and and `self` as second argument to  `super()`:

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Vehicle __init__() called')

class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Car, self).__init__()

car = Car()
```

But this is not enough:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: must be type, not classobj
```

`class Vehicle:` creates an old-style class. `Vehicle` has to inherit from `object` to get a new-style class that works with `super()`:

```
class Vehicle(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Vehicle __init__() called')

class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Car, self).__init__()

car = Car()
```

prints:

```
Vehicle __init__() called
```

### super() without arguments in Python 2

Having to remember these two arguments all the time is kind of annoying. Fortunately, there is a solution. The highly recommended library [Python-Future](http://python-future.org) allows you to use `super()` without arguments in Python 2:

```
from builtins import object, super # from Python-Future

class Vehicle(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Vehicle __init__() called')

class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

car = Car()
```

prints:

```
Vehicle __init__() called
```

Answer (score 6):

`super()` doesn't know what class it's being called in. You have to tell it which class's parent's method you want to get. E.g. `super(Car, self).__init__(self, name, color)` in your code.